# What is an umbrella in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request

I realize that the English word "umbrella" smells like a diminutive of *umbra*, "shadow".
However, all mentions of an "umbrella" from ancient Rome or Greece I have found concern protection from the Sun, whereas I am interested in umbrellas as a means of protection against rain.
(This may have something to do with my being now in Cambridge rather than Texas.)
It appears that this kind of umbrella against rain was not known in ancient Rome — do correct me if I'm wrong.

What would be a good Latin word for an umbrella?
There is no need for it to be classical (unless there is good classical precedent, of course), I just want a useful word for present day.
An attested phrase would be great, but other kinds of suggestions are also welcome.
I have posted one possibility below, but I'm sure there are other ones, or at least better reasoning for mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have several times used *parapluvium* (cf. Fr. *parapluie*) in published translations. Nobody has ever objected.

Comment: I like this a lot, especially in its relationship to _parapluie_ and its contrast with _parasol_. But following the example of both _parapluie_ and _parasol_, I wonder if _parapluvia_ would be a closer rendition, as _pluvia_ is the substantive rain (as is _pluie_ and _sol_), from the adjective _pluvius_? On reflection though, _parapluvium_ does sound nice, certainly nicer than _parapluvia_, and euphony is as good a guide to word formation as any, I guess :)

Comment: @Penelope I've wrestled with this one for years, on and off. Looking at some old notes I see that I did indeed begin with _parapluvia_, but was uncomfortable with it. I adopted a correspondent's suggestion for the neuter form, because it (a) was used in _tempus pluvium_ and (b) was more euphonious, as you say.

Comment: An aside: in Spanish is _paraguas_, from para+agua, stop water. What do you mean nobody has ever objected?

Comment: @luchonacho I mean just that! You'd be surprised at some of the things in my translations that people choose to cavil at — but _parapluvium_ isn't one of them.

Answer (score 3):

An umbrella can be regarded as a "shadow from rain", similar to the "shadow from light" expressed by *umbra*.
I think this analogy is clear enough, but it has to be made explicit.
To me it seems that *umbra* or the diminutive *umbrella* means a shadow from light unless specified.
So, we specify it: I suggest ***umbrella pluvialis***.

Of course this would make sense with *umbra* as well, but the diminutive is suitable for this use — the shadow zone created by an umbrella is rather small — and it reinforces the meaning by analogy to other languages like English ("umbrella") and Italian ("ombrello").
And, as usual, once the concept has been introduced and the context doesn't turn sunny, the adjective *pluvialis* can be dropped to leave a plain *umbrella*.

I have found no attestations of *umbrella pluvialis*, but I think it would be a reasonable choice anyway, especially in modern use.

Penelope remarked in a comment that *umbrella* seems not to be the standard classical choice, whereas *umbella* or *umbraculum* (often in plural) are attested.
[Lexicon Recentis Latinitatis](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/institutions_connected/latinitas/documents/rc_latinitas_20040601_lexicon_it.html) agrees.
These are good options with *pluvialis/pluviale*.
However, despite *umbrella* not being classical, I find it appropriate for modern use.
After all, Latin diminutives are not uniquely determined by the base word.
And the analogy to other languages is not to be neglected; making use of them often makes communication smoother.